# DataQ stuck in CDC mode

Tags: serial-port, instruments, drive, libusb, cdc

I have dataQ plugged into a bunch of circuits in the lab that I use to measure Voltage V. Suddenly, I tried to connect to the dataQ in my laptop for the usual testing, but the device did not show up in the "Windaq dashboard"  software. The device shows up in the device manager as "COM3". I did some research and I found out that means that the device is in CDC mode and I need it to be in LibUSB mode for it to be detected. to do that the manual says to hold on to the control button after 5s from connecting to the computer until the LED light turns red.

My problem:

I pressed and was holding the button for 1 minute but it never went red. am I misunderstanding the problem ? Any help from experienced people is appreciated.

(Note: I am using DI-4108)

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer from the company itself:

> keep pressing the control button as fast as possible and after that press and hold it until the LED is red